# Phone field type and search using phone number in servicenow CRM

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

## 1.What are the Phone field types available in servicenow CRM

i noticed below two types

```
1)  Phone Number(Only with standard fields like Business phone,mobile phone,home phone in customer contact) 
2)  Phone Number(E164)(while creating/editing a custom field).
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F99Of.png)

## 2.And what is the difference between both types and why the phone number type is not avilable while creating new field.

Below are my findings

Phone field type:

With standard phone fields like Business phone and Mobile Phone the type shown as Phone Number and also the bahaviour is, it is changing the format
to (314) 567-8912 (both in UI and stored in CRM as this format) when i try to save number like 3145678912.

With type Phone Number(E164) - it is listing the countries(territorries) and also applying validation rules in CRM UI and storing the number with 
coutrycode and phone number for eg +918012345678.

Search Phone number:

When search a phone number in CRM UI or with REST API only with exact Format only it is fetching record.
For eg : if number is stored in this format (314) 567-8912, only search with (314) 567-8912 is resulting the record ,is there any way to fetch this format record in alternative way

https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/contact?sysparm_query=phoneSTARTSWITH(314) 567-8912 - >is working

https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/contact?sysparm_query=phoneSTARTSWITH3145678912 -> it is not fetching record

https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/contact?sysparm_query=phoneLIKE3145678912->it is also not fetching

It seems search with the exact format only works-> am i right? 
Please correct me if anything is wrong

Comment: Not exactly. phoneSTARTSWITH checks for a phone record starting with given number. If you are trying to query in contact table it will try to find a contact with phone number starting with your desire input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :).Yes i am having a phone record in contacts table with the number (314) 567-8912. When i try to search the record  with STARTSWITH or LIKE with the same format that is without removing anything from number ,it is fetching record.   But when i remove braces and hyphen like this 3145678912,it is not returning result in API.                                 
 FYI: this phone field type is Phone NUMBER not Phone NUMBER E164